# If I know .NET 4.0 is installed on a user's machine, can I assume .NET 2.0 is as well?

Tags: c#, .net, c++

Pretty self-explanatory question, but here's a bit of context:

My app (C++, unmanaged) has a feature written as a C# app. This feature is only available when we know .NET is installed. So, must I maintain separate versions of this C# application for each framework version we want to support, or will a lowest-common-denominator of .NET 2.0 work (thus, if we detect any framework installed >= 2.0, we know we will be OK)?

Note that I *prefer* to just maintain a single .NET 2.0 version of our C# app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [.NET framework dependencies page for .NET 4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb822049.aspx) on MSDN says that yes, you can count on it:

> You do not have to install previous versions of the .NET Framework or
>   the CLR before you install the latest version; each version provides
>   the necessary components.

Answer (score 6):

You can assume that .net 2.0 apps will run on the 4.0 runtime.

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff602939.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Yes, if you write and build your application against .Net 2.0, it will work with all versions going forward.

Comment: @PoweRoy: Isn't that what he meant by "going forward"?

Answer (score 1):

Yes... (.net 2 will work on .net 4)

Answer (score 1):

I met a problem with mixed-mode assemblies like SharpSvn, which needed CLR v.2 to run, while my app was compiled for .NET 4, so we had to install both versions of the framework.
Still I believe it's not your case.

Comment: +1 this is an important caveat - net 2.0 applications that reference mixed-mode assemblies will **not** work on a machine with only .net 4.0 installed by default. You can fix it using <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true"> in your app.config instead of having to install both though.

Answer (score 0):

yes it has back compatibility assured , i have done this with .net 3 & 3.5sp1 and they are currently running on .net 4 without any problem.